# module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping' how to safely reinstall update-notifier-common?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

When running `app upgrade` I get the following errors:

```
$ sudo sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for admin-federico-dostuni:
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease
Fetched 172 kB in 1s (176 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.1.15) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Debian/deb822.py", line 78, in <module>
    class TagSectionWrapper(collections.Mapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Looking online it looks like that the issue is caused by a missing `collections.Mapping` attribute in the `debian.deb822` module. To resolve the issue I should:

1. List item

Remove the package `update-notifier-common`

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq update-notifier-common
```

2. Update apt, and reinstall `update-notifier-common`

```
sudo apt-get install update-notifier-common
```

The problem is that I can't pass the 1st step because I got this error message:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq update-notifier-common
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of update-notifier-common:
 ubuntu-server depends on update-notifier-common.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
```

I checked `update-notifier-common` dependencies and it doesn't look good:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends update-notifier-common
update-notifier-common
Reverse Depends:
  update-notifier
  flashplugin-installer
  ubuntu-server
  debconf
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  apt-config-auto-update
  reboot-notifier
  apt-config-auto-update
  update-notifier
  debconf
  ubuntu-server
  byobu
```

How can I safely remove `update-notifier-common` without messing up the whole OS?

Comment: Did you manually install a different python3 version?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195545/module-collections-has-no-attribute-mapping-issue-on-macos-for-sdk-installa

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I have manually installed Python 3.10.9 and now my OS have 3 python version, however I configured `update-alternatives` and set python 3.10.9 as default version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue isn't `update-notifier-common` but the python version I have on this machine.

Comment: That's obviously true, so all you need to do is to reconfigure update-alternatives to use the original Python version as the default version.